# sqldumper error when trying to run dtexec with project deployment model

Tags: ssis, dtexec

I have a SSIS project with several packages which uses the Project deployment model, which means that there are project level parameters and connections.

Beacuse of this reason, to execute the packages using `dtexec`, it's necessary to use two parameters to specify the project, to get the connections and parameters from, and the package.

To do so, first you have to build the project to get the `.ispac` file which will be provided to the `/project` parameter.

And then you have to invoke `dtexec` like this:

```
dtexec.exe /project ".ispac file name" /package ".dtsx file name"
```

The problem is that when I invoke `dtexec` like this:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe"
/Package "d:\MyProjectPath\MyPackage.dtsx"
/Project "d:\MyProject\ProjectName.ispac"
```

I get an ugly `sqldumper` error, like this:

```
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, AdjustTokenPrivileges () completed with status (00000514)
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Input parameters: 4 supplied
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,   Parameter 1: 11176
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,   Parameter 2: 0
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,   Parameter 3: 0:0
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,   Parameter 4: 002FC778
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Parsed parameters:
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ProcessID = 11176
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ThreadId = 0
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     Flags = 0x0
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     MiniDumpFlags = 0x0
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     SqlInfoPtr = 0x002FC778
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     DumpDir = <NULL>
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ExceptionRecordPtr = 0x00000000
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ContextPtr = 0x00000000
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ExtraFile = <NULL>
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     PatternForExtraFiles = <NULL>
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     InstanceName = <NULL>
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ServiceName = <NULL>
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Callback type 11 not used
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Callback type 15 not used
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Callback type 7 not used
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, MiniDump completed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\ErrorDumps\SQLDmpr0035.mdmp
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Total Buffer pool data pages filtered out: 0 KB
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Location of module 'dbghelp.dll' : 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\dbghelp.dll'
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, File version of module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\dbghelp.dll' : '6.12:2.633'
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Product version of module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\dbghelp.dll' : '6.12:2.633'
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Location of module 'sqldumper.exe' : 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\SQLDUMPER.EXE'
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, File version of module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\SQLDUMPER.EXE' : '2014.120:2000.8'
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Product version of module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared\SQLDUMPER.EXE' : '12.0:2000.8'
(3240:2660) 12/15/16 16:45:09, ACTION,                sysfer.dll, Watson Invoke: No
```

How can I run the package without getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is easy to solve: in the `/package` parameter, instead of specifying the package path like `d:\MyProjectPath\MyPackage.dtsx` you have to specify only the package name, like this `MyPackage.dtsx`

I think the explanation is that the package is searched for inside the deployed `.ispac` file, so, if you don't specify the package name you get a weird error.