# sqldumper error leads to C drive getting full

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, polybase

I've installed Microsoft SQL Server 2019 following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aff9jwSPRTU&list=LLfbVoI77Ues8vJH7egp6q5Q&index=3&t=0s). At 10:30 it was advised to change the User database directory, the User log directory and the backup directory from default to directories on drive D.

Now I got dump files being generated at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\Polybase\dump`

Here's the snippet from `SQLDUMPER_ERRORLOG.log`:

```
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, AdjustTokenPrivileges () completed with status (00000514)
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Input parameters: 4 supplied
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,   Parameter 1: 25340
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,   Parameter 2: 0
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,   Parameter 3: 0:0
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,   Parameter 4: 00007FF62791B360
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Parsed parameters:
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ProcessID = 25340
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ThreadId = 0
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     Flags = 0x0
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     MiniDumpFlags = 0x0
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     SqlInfoPtr = 0x00007FF62791B360
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     DumpDir = <NULL>
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ExceptionRecordPtr = 0x0000000000000000
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ContextPtr = 0x0000000000000000
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ExtraFile = <NULL>
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     PatternForExtraFiles = <NULL>
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     InstanceName = <NULL>
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ServiceName = <NULL>
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION,               mpdwsvc.exe, Not creating an additional dump, because dump for stack signature 00000001AB5F1D21 already exists.
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION,               mpdwsvc.exe, Send_To_Watson flag is set to true
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION,               mpdwsvc.exe, Force_Watson flag is set to true
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION,               mpdwsvc.exe, Watson Invoke: Yes
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION,               mpdwsvc.exe, Creating WER report...
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION,               mpdwsvc.exe, Created the report.
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION,               mpdwsvc.exe, WerReportAddFile Mini Dump succeeded.
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:19:45, ACTION,               mpdwsvc.exe, Submitting WER report...
(9E04:9E08) 12/08/19 21:22:49, ACTION,               mpdwsvc.exe, Submitted report synchronously.
```

I looked up the error and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168118/sqldumper-error-when-trying-to-run-dtexec-with-project-deployment-model). The answer says to change the package path in the `\package` parameter.

How do I find where to change the package parameters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That linked question is related to SSIS whereas your issue appears to be Polybase related - based on the dump file path.

Have a look at [this article](https://nielsberglund.com/2019/11/20/fix-polybase-in-sql-server-2019-developers-edition/) and see if the issues described there match your experince.

Comment: this helped me a lot!! thank you very much!